# Moving from UK to Germany: do I need a customs declaration

Tags: united-kingdom, relocation, customs

I am moving from he UK to Germany in May.
I am considering to move my personal belongings (e.g. clothes, books, laptops, electric guitars, lps, and other kitchen things) by van.

I read the customs instructions and as far as I can understand I can declare personal goods by conduct or orally only. However, some removal companies are indicating that I would need to pay for customs declaration.

Hence, I am a bit confused on how the procedure is, i.e. do I need to prepare a declaration and pay for it.

Any advice or link that clarify this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Which customs instructions did you read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the instructions you read mentioned an oral declaration then you probably found the customs instructions concerning [travel](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/travel_node.html) rather than those concerning [transfer of residence](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Staying-in-Germany/Transferring-residence/transferring-residence_node.html).

To avoid paying duty when you transfer residence, you need "special relief," because the amounts involved exceed the duty free allowance.  From the second page:

> In the case of goods for which it is intended to claim special relief, the application for release for free circulation must always be made in writing...

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. I mainly read the info about the UK, which were not at all clear to me.

Comment: In other words I am not sure at all whether I need to declare something in the UK

Comment: @efrem You do not need to declare anything when you leave the UK.  You are taking stuff _out_ of the UK.  Taking stuff _in_ to Germany (or any country) is a much more involved process (I have done it to Switzerland, and watched my son moving to the UK from Germany)